# Open a div aside to a web page from chrome extension( like dev tools panel displays)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

In the extension that I'm developing currently, I want to open a div inside underlying web page. Though I was able to do so, now I want to display that div like the way chrome dev tools panel open.

This is how it currently shown.
[image]

How I want it to display.
[image]

Currently, website content is covered with the div as you can see in the first picture. I want to display the yellow div in a way how dev tools panel is displayed.

**content.js**

```
    document.documentElement.style.height = '100%';
    document.body.style.height = '100%';
    document.documentElement.style.width = '70%';
    document.body.style.width = '100%';

    var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
    var btn = document.createElement( 'BUTTON' );

    var content = document.createTextNode( `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing...`);

    document.documentElement.appendChild( div );
    div.appendChild(btn)
    div.appendChild(content)

    div.id = 'myDivId';
    div.style.position = 'fixed';
    div.style.top = '0%';
    div.style.left = '70%';
    div.style.width = '30%';   
    div.style.height = '100%';
    div.style.overflowY = "auto"
    div.style.zIndex = 150000
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.innerHTML = 'Create';
    btn.style.marginTop = "5%"
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    btn.style.position = 'absolute';
    btn.style.left = '50%';
```

Comment: You can't do it in Chrome. Some other browsers have a sidebar API for extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you for letting me know..

Comment: It works in desired way only when the web page is a PDF. otherwise no.